# Cannot access Xrm.Page.context from within HTML web resource in CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I'm trying access the Xrm.Page.data object from within an HTML web resource. I try to access the Xrm context, I find that it is undefined or that Xrm.Page is null. The code for the web resource is as follows:

```
function GetClientUrl() {
        if (typeof window.parent.Xrm.Page.context == "object") {
            clientUrl = window.parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
        }
        var ServicePath = "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web";
        return clientUrl + ServicePath;
    }
```

It's just appen when it's embedded in an HTML web resource. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft provided a function to get the context for web resources.

You need to add a reference to:

```
<script src="../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Then you can get the context like so:

```
var context = GetGlobalContext();
clientUrl = context.getClientUrl();
```

Documentation: [GetGlobalContext function and ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx (client-side reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328541.aspx#BKMK_GetGlobalContext)

Answer (score 1):

Reference [ClientGlobalContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328541.aspx#BKMK_ClientGlobalContext_js_aspx) on your web resource and you should then be able to access Xrm object like you do on any CRM form. You don't have to access the parent page's Xrm object.

```
<head>
<title>HTML Web Resource</title>
<script src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>
```